# Maximum capacity of std::vector<std::string> on IBM i

Tags: c++, ibm-midrange, stdvector

Recently I've discovered strange behaviour of sizing `std::vector` on ibm i.
So, when you define

`std::vector<std::string> vec;`

System returns around 87M for `vec.max_size();`

However, when I do:

`vec.reserve(400000);` or even more it fails with no memory exception
and corresponding inquiry: `Signal SIGABRT raised (abnormal termination).`

I've finally figured out that 300k is some kind of threshold for vector of strings for code to run.

Here is the log:

```
Procedure:          _CXX_PEP__Fv                                                                                                   
      TESTPGM      TESTLIB      7                                       CALLER     0000000000000036 TESTPGM      QTEMP        Н      
Procedure:          main
      TESTPGM      TESTLIB      4                                       CALLER     0000000000000036 TESTPGM      QTEMP        Н      
Procedure:          reserve__Q2_3std6vectorXTQ2_3std12basic_stringXTcTQ2_3std11char_traitsXTc_TQ2_3std9allocatorXTc__TQ2_3std9allo 
torXTQ2_3std12basic_stringXTcTQ2_3std11char_traitsXTc_TQ2_3std9allocatorXTc____FUi                                                 
      TESTPGM      TESTLIB      1                                       CALLER     0000000000000036 TESTPGM      QTEMP        Н      
Procedure:          allocate__Q2_3std9allocatorXTQ2_3std12basic_stringXTcTQ2_3std11char_traitsXTc_TQ2_3std9allocatorXTc___FUiPCv   
      TESTPGM      TESTLIB      1                                       CALLER     0000000000000036 TESTPGM      QTEMP        Н      
Procedure:          _Allocate__3stdHQ2_3std12basic_stringXTcTQ2_3std11char_traitsXTc_TQ2_3std9allocatorXTc___UiPQ2_3std12basic_str 
gXTcTQ2_3std11char_traitsXTc_TQ2_3std9allocatorXTc___PQ2_3std12basic_stringXTcTQ2_3std11char_traitsXTc_TQ2_3std9allocatorXTc__     
      QYPPRT370  QSYS         12                                        CALLER     0000000000000036 NWSCTODF37 QBUILDSS1    Н      
Procedure:          __nw__FUi                                                                                                      
      QYPPRT370  QSYS         2                                         CALLER     0000000000000036 NOMEMORY37 QBUILDSS1    Н      
Procedure:          _Nomemory__3stdFv                                                                                              
      QYPPRT370  QSYS         11                                        CALLER     0000000000000036 THROW37    QBUILDSS1    Н      
Procedure:          __Throw                                                                                                        
      QYPPRT370  QSYS         24                                        CALLER     0000000000000036 DOTHROW37  QBUILDSS1    Н
Procedure:          __DoThrow                                                                                                
      QYPPRT370  QSYS         16                                        CALLER     0000000000000036 EXCEPTIO37 QBUILDSS1    Н
Procedure:          terminate__3stdFv                                                                                        
      QYPPRT370  QSYS         1                                         CALLER     0000000000000036 EXCEPTIO37 QBUILDSS1    Н
Procedure:          myabort__3stdFv                                                                                          
      QC2UTIL1   QSYS         2                                         CALLER     0000000000000036 QC2TERM    QBUILDSS1    Н
Procedure:          abort                                                                                                    
      QC2UTIL1   QSYS         6                                         CALLER     0000000000000036 QC2SIGNL   QBUILDSS1    Н
Procedure:          raise                                                                                                    
      QMHPDEH    QSYS                                              012E *DFTACTGRP 0000000000000001                         Н
      QMHUNMSG   QSYS                                              0196 *DFTACTGRP 0000000000000001                         Н
      QMHAPD     QSYS                                              02EC *DFTACTGRP 0000000000000001                         Н
```

There are `CPUTIME      *NOMAX` and `MAXTMPSTG    *NOMAX` set for this job.

So, I wonder if ibm limits me with 300k elements vector or I've messed up somewhere.

Or ibm just forcing me to use vector of vectors due to some reason?

I'm on i OS 7.3 TR5 if that matters

Comment: It depends on the limits in your virtual address space. How much RAM do you have? Did you enable [memory overcommitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following program:

```
#include <vector>                      
#include <string>                      
int  main(void)                        
{                                      
  int i;                               
  std::vector<std::string> * vec;      
  i = vec->max_size();                 
  vec = new std::vector<std::string>;  

  vec->reserve(i);                     
  delete vec;                          
  return 0;                            
}                                      

I compiled as follows: 
CRTCPPMOD MODULE(TEST) DBGVIEW(*ALL) TERASPACE(*YES *TSIFC) STGMDL(*TERASPACE) 
  DTAMDL(*LLP64) RTBND(*LLP64)                                       
CRTPGM PGM(TEST) STGMDL(*TERASPACE)
```

This shows that max_size returns 178,956,970, a much larger value than you saw.

However, passing this to reserve() causes a sigabort and kills the job !

I was able to pass 89000000 to reserve() successfully, however,  (filling the vector with strings may well cause a crash however!)

I'm not sure of all the gory details, but I suspect it is largely related to non-teraspace implementation of heap (which limits contiguous storage to about 16MB) vs. Teraspace where the limit is 4GB of contiguously addressable allocation. You can play with the options I specified to see what happens.

Notice I allocated the vector in heap.  Things might be different for a stack or staticly allocated vector.

Comment: thanks for teraspace thing. I'll try it, seems like it was root cause of runtime errors

Answer (score 3):

`vactor::max_size()` is just going to give you theoretical values.

Whether you can actually allocate memory for those many elements will depend on actual memory available at runtime.

Comment: ok sir. in this case I'm able to allocate some additional 10M for std::string, but can not add even 100K for std::vector<std::string>. Does vector comsume that much memory?

Comment: Remember `vector` needs contiguous memory.

Comment: Ok, so maybe I should stick with other container type (`std::list` comes to mind)